Logstash fails to start on Windows 11 using basic config
I am trying to launch Logstash for the first time on this Windows 11 laptop. I downloaded and unzipped version 8.15, and I created the following logstash-simple.conf config file in the logstash root
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => json_lines
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "spring-boot-logs"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}

Then from a windows command line (tried powershell, cygwin, and old fashioned dos prompt) I called
.\bin\logstash.bat -f c:\config-dir\logstash-simple.conf

This always gives me the same error
[2024-10-13T12:44:58,216][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2024-10-13T12:44:58,231][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2024-10-13T12:44:58,248][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2024-10-13T12:44:58,257][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:921) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:880) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.programs.elk.dup.logstash_minus_8_dot_15_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\programs\elk\dup\logstash-8.15.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:90) ~[?:?]


Could you turn on the debug log.level ? The config pipeline seems correct.
